# JedisCluster works in 2.7.x but doesn't work in Jedis 2.9.x with JedisConnectionException and Connection refused

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have my code in Jedis 2.7.x for several months. But i found I have the same issue as https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1625 (JedisPool.getResource block when redis server restart). So I switched from 2.7.x to 2.9.x. I am using the same code to create JedisCluster. But it failed to connect and get data from Jedis.

I created a singleton JedisCluster instance and every time i just use JedisCluster.get() to get data. I don't close connections for cluster.

More info: My redis is 3.2.8. I am using the one single host as JedisCluster and there is no slave. The reason why i want to use JedisCluster mode instead of Jedis mode is that I have another system need to call a JedisCluster with multi-hosts. I want to test the code in the current single-host cluster first and then deploy the code to that system

```
cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:1
cluster_size:1
cluster_current_epoch:0
cluster_my_epoch:0
cluster_stats_messages_sent:0
cluster_stats_messages_received:0
```

Same code worked in 2.7.x but not 2.9.x.

```
@Singleton
JedisCluster jedisCluster(){
        Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("10.xx.xx.xx", 6379));
        GenericObjectPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(16);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(16);
        return new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes, 2000, 1000, 5, jedisPoolConfig);
}
//When using cluster
jedisCluster.set("foo", "bar");
String value = jedisCluster.get("foo");
```

Below code worked in 2.9.x

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("xx.xx.xxx.xx",6379);
System.out.println(jedis.get("foo"));
```

I ssh to my Redis host and run the cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get foo
"bar
```

Exception that i am getting

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:66) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:31) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.get(JedisCluster.java:124) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
.........
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
... 45 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.9.x.jar:?]
... 45 more
```

log in redis side

```
3088:M 21 Mar 21:42:24.187 - Accepted xx.xx.xxx.xxx:36064
3088:M 21 Mar 21:42:24.197 - Accepted xx.xx.xxx.xxx:36065
3088:M 21 Mar 21:42:24.212 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
3088:M 21 Mar 21:42:28.481 - DB 0: 12407076 keys (0 volatile) in 16777216 slots HT.
3088:M 21 Mar 21:42:28.482 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1852164712 bytes in use
```

https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1792

Comment: Disable firewall

Comment: I feel firewall may not be the problem because my system can connect to JedisCluster in Jedis 2.7.x and can use Jedis by "new Jedis("xx.xx.xxx.xx",6379)" in Jedis 2.9.x. The only problem is it cannot connect to JedisCluster in Jedis 2.9.x.

Comment: More info: My redis is 3.2.8. I am using the one single host as JedisCluster and there is no slave. The reason why i want to use JedisCluster mode instead of Jedis mode is that I have another system need to call a JedisCluster with multi-hosts. I want to test the code in the current single-host cluster first and then deploy the code to that system.

Answer (score 1):

My question got answered by Marcos Nils in jedis github - https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1792 which pointed me to https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/pull/1211

Previously I didn't create cluster in my single host and I could directly use it as a cluster in 2.7.x. I ran the below command which solved my problem.

```
for i in {0..16383}; do bin/redis-cli -h <ipOfHost1> CLUSTER ADDSLOTS $i; done
cluster meet <ip> 6379
```